# how to convert this OR operator to case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case, query-optimization, where-clause

i have the below query, i want to know about the case statement by changing the below type of operator.

```
SELECT t_product.a_productid,
t_product.a_mpactive,
t_product.a_active,
trim(substring_index(a_reference,'_',-1)) as a_reference,
t_product.a_shopid,
t_productlang.a_name,
t_deactivatedproduct.a_reason
FROM t_deactivatedproduct
inner join
(SELECT max(a_deactivatedproductid) as a_deactivatedproductid
FROM t_deactivatedproduct
GROUP by t_deactivatedproduct.a_productid) as a on a.a_deactivatedproductid = t_deactivatedproduct.a_deactivatedproductid
INNER JOIN t_product ON t_product.a_productid = t_deactivatedproduct.a_productid
INNER JOIN t_productlang ON t_product.a_productid = t_productlang.a_productid AND t_product.a_shopid IN(2,3,5,6,7,10,8,15,12,16,17,26,27,28)
WHERE t_product.a_ispublished = 1
AND ((t_product.a_active = 1 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 0)
OR (t_product.a_active = 0 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 1)
OR (t_product.a_active = 0 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 0))
ORDER BY t_deactivatedproduct.a_deactivatedproductid DESC limit 700;
```

Comment: Why? It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: hi @jarlh, I want to analyze the changes, I wonder how it can be changed to the case statement.

Comment: wouldn't `t_product.a_active = 0` be sufficient to replace the 2nd and 3rd lines?

Comment: no cuz the logic is like (0/1,1/0,0/0) but not (1/1) @GMB explained below please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` is probably not the best pick to express such boolean logic. MySQL, however, understands tuple equality, so you could rewrite this:

```
AND (
    (t_product.a_active = 1 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 0)
    OR (t_product.a_active = 0 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 1)
    OR (t_product.a_active = 0 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 0)
)
```

As:

```
AND (t_product.a_active, t_product.a_mpactive) in ( (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0) )
```

That will make the query neater, but not necessarily faster. Under the hood, the optimizer rewrites the query and both expressions might be ultimately interpreted similarly.

---

If we were to phrase this with `CASE`, we would have to wrap it somehow, to make it look like a predicate. Something like:

```sql
AND 1 = CASE
    WHEN t_product.a_active = 1 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 0 THEN 1
    WHEN t_product.a_active = 0 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN t_product.a_active = 0 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 0 THEN 1
END
```

---

... And, for what it's worth... If both columns always store non-null boolean values (0/1), then the condition is simpler phrased as a negation:

```sql
WHERE NOT (t_product.a_active = 1 AND t_product.a_mpactive = 1)
```

Or:

```
WHERE (t_product.a_active, t_product.a_mpactive) not in ( (1, 1) )
```

Comment: nice and thanks, but I want to see is possible for we can rewrite it into the case statement. if yes can you add that to the answer cuz I wonder how this type of operator can able to change. @GMB

Comment: Thank you so much and well-explained @GMB. have a great day. :)